# Multiple nested subscribe with conditionals and keeping all the data from all the subscribes?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I require multiple calls to the services with subscribe, but each service api call is dependent on the previous call's data. I need to keep a record of all the data for each subscribe. I also have some conditions for some nested subscribe calls. I have heard nested subscribe is bad and would like advice on best way to go about this. TIA.

```
    callServices(){
        this.rServices.getHouse(houseId).subscribe(house =>{
          if(condition){
            this.rServices.callIfMethod().subscribe(data => {
              ....
            })
          } else {
            let roomInfo = house.roomInfo;
            this.rServices.getRooms(roomInfo.getRoomId()).subscribe(data => {
              let a = data;
              // conditional if ElementSchemaRegistry
              if(conditional) {
              this.rServices.getFurniture(a.getFurnitureId())
              } else {
                ....
              }
            })
          }
        })
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `flatMap` and `map`:

```js
this.rServies.getHouse(houseId).pipe(
  // add 'callIfMethod' data
  flatMap(house => {
    if (condition) {
      // combine this result with house
      return this.rServices.callIfMethod(houseId).pipe(
        map(data => ({data, house}))
      )
    }

    return of({house})
  }),
  // add room info
  flatMap(({house, data}) => {
    if (!condition) {
      return this.rServices.getRooms(house.roomInfo.getRoomId()).pipe(
        map(room => ({house, data, room}))
      )
    }

   return of({house, data})
  }),
  // add furniture
  flatMap(({house, data, room}) => {
    if (...) {
      return getFurniture(...).pipe(map(furniture => ({house, data, room, furniture}))
    }
    return of({house,data,room})
  }),
  ...
).subscribe({house, data, room, furniture, ...}) => ...)
```